# Static or instance class for reuse between RFC calls?

Tags: oop, memory, abap, saprfc

I am implementing some piece of functionality which must be called in the remote system, so I wrap this functionality into a global class which would be called by an RFC module. The calculations to be done are rather complex, heavy and involve many DB calls, so I am seeking ways to pre-save some results for the future RFC calls. The module will be called very frequently and this trick can save many seconds of runtime.

**The question is:** should I use static class or instance class in my RFC wrapper?

The idea is to put calculation results into itab attributes of the class and re-use them in future calls. This data will have some validity interval though and after expiration of time it will be invalidated and re-calculated again.

In [SAP recommendations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenstatic_class_singleton_guidl.htm) we see that static classes generally are not recommended with some exceptions, and for re-use SAP recommends to stick to singletones. Does the singleton idea applies to my use-case as well?

In my understanding if I put tables into the attributes of static class they will be alive in memory for a while (from ABAPDOCU):

> They are persisted in the memory for as long as the current internal session exists

and as can be seen from this magnificent [figure by Sandra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235435/911419)

[image]

the user session will be reused (for how long?) between RFC calls, and so my saved tables/attributes will be reused too.

It is better than [shared memory](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenuse_shared_memory_guidl.htm) which has its overhead and disadvantages, e.g. it is valid only for current AS instance.

Is ir a viable idea or I'd better stick to singleton with instance class?

Comment: Why so complicated? Why don’t you simply store the buffer data in the database? By this it remains valid as long as you need it - no need for guessing the session lifetime. It‘s also available on all server instances, and a single, potentially buffered database read is still a lot faster than repeating expensive calculations.

Comment: The user session is kept opened as long as the calling program doesn't terminate and you don't close the connection explicitly (function module `RFC_CONNECTION_CLOSE`, explained in the [ABAP documentation of the RFC session](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrfc_context.htm)) and the timeout is not reached (defined in the profile parameter `rdisp/max_wprun_time` or its successors described in the note [2918906](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2918906)).

Comment: I think that it's always better to prefer instance members by default, especially for unit testing and mocking, but using static members would be a valid solution technically speaking.

Comment: `Why don’t you simply store the buffer data in the database?` isn't keeping data in memory faster than DB-table? I believe it is. The concept I'm trying to replicate is the shared memory without actually using SHMA

Comment: `and the timeout is not reached (defined in the profile parameter rdisp/max_wprun_time` and this timeout is the same for JCo connections? My module will be called through JCo

Comment: `and a single, potentially buffered database read is still a lot faster than repeating expensive calculations` the problem is that calculations should be repeated anyway, because of their impermanence (pricing conditions), i.e.they have validity interval disregard of the storage type they will be persisted to (DB or memory). So I cannot just fetch all the data from standard tables and put it into my buffer-table, data are calculated **on-the-fly**, and there will be database CRUD overhead

Comment: I realize that my comment was misleading. The profile parameter `rdisp/max_wprun_time` defines the timeout while running code in a "**dialog workprocess**" (RFC + SAP GUI screens), it's not about the lifetime of the RFC session. The timeout cannot be specific to JCO, the timeout applies to any code running in a dialog workprocess (JCO is a client framework which calls ABAP code in the ABAP server via RFC).

Comment: I'm not sure if it could help you since I don't know how it performs, but you can serialize an ABAP object instance with CALL TRANSFORMATION and store it easily in a DB to then restore the instance exactly as it was, the only thing it will change is the instance ID. Check the ABAP Freakshow Ep. 10 video about this.

Comment: @SandraRossi, so I got confused with the many timeout types you are speaking about. Is dialog `wprun` timeout is the same as RFC session timeout that I am interested in (= user session lifetime = static class lifetime)? Or user session is determined by two timeouts (dialog + RFC)?

Comment: `can serialize an ABAP object instance with CALL TRANSFORMATION and store it easily in a DB` I see no improvement here, 'cause serializing object to DB is even slower than direct itab insert into DB. It's additional overhead of serialization/deserialization

Comment: Concerning the lifetime of the RFC sessions, there is the profile parameter **`gw/gw_disconnect`** for defining the timeout when there is no activity (30 minutes by default). It seems that there are some other gw parameters which could be related to the lifetime of the RFC sessions.

Comment: Thanks. And BTW, as far as I understand my client's landscape, my RFC will be invoked through JCo which passes Gateway and uses CPIC connection, can it influence RFC lifetime too? Is there any consolidated SAP note which lists all of the parameters that make impact on RFC session lifetime?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with static classes vs. singletons is more of a question of code style. When you implement the singleton pattern, then the instance is stored in a static attribute. So there is no difference between a singleton and an all-static class when it comes to persistence. And that persistence is only through the internal session. The internal sessions of RFC calls [are bound to the RFC session](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenrfc_context.htm). When the caller is another ABAP program running on a different server, then it will keep its RFC session while it is running, just like a regular internal session would. So you can use static attributes to cache data within one execution of one program, but you can not use them to share data between multiple executions of the program. (When the RFC call comes from a non-ABAP program, then the lifetime of the RFC session will end when the program explicitly closes the session).

So should you use a static class / singleton here? Only if all those requests happen through one run of the same program (but then why don't you cache on the client or create an RFC function module which accepts requests in bulk?)

- The program is only executed once by one user

If you have multiple requests from multiple users, then you have a typical use-case for shared memory. The argument about the shared memory instance being bound to the application server is pretty irrelevant here, because RFC user sessions are also bound to an application server.

If you need caching *across* application servers, then there is the option to cache on the database server by creating a database table to cache the results of more time-consuming queries. But retrieving those results would still require a database request, so it only makes sense for queries which take several seconds to complete and still don't return much data. They are not useful for queries which just take milliseconds or where the reason for the runtime is the amount of data they return.

Comment: `then the lifetime of the RFC session will end when the program explicitly closes the session` do you have any chance to try it with JCo? [According to SAP experts](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11836748/how-and-when-is-a-jco-connection-closed-in-version.html) it behave much more complicated than just calling `disconnectIfAlive()` Do you now JCo parameters that influence connection lifetime?

Comment: @Suncatcher Sorry, but I have no experience with the SAP Java Connector.

Comment: `If you have multiple requests from multiple users, then you have a typical use-case for shared memory` no, in my configuration the user and app always be the same. BTW, is there any way to have shared memory really shared across instances? We never know which instance will accept RFC call, what solutions are usually applied to such cases?

Comment: @Suncatcher When you have only one user running only one program, then why don't you cache on the client-side?

Comment: It's a tricky question, maybe worth thinks about. The first thing is that I am not a developer on a Java side, the second is that approach seems more complicated. As I wrote in question, the cached data will be outdated very fast, so it needs to be cached no more than for 2-4 hours, and having them cached on Java client we need to send an invalidation token and to reload them again from backend. And the third, the most horrible, every 2-3h we need to pull a huge tables over the network to Java, it will be hundreds-thousands of records. Having all this stuff done in backed is much more elegant.

Comment: `or create an RFC function module which accepts requests in bulk?` could you please describe more in detail this technique or give a link to documentation? how bulked requests will help me for this use-case?

Comment: @Suncatcher The idea is that you create a function module which doesn't take one request but a whole table of requests and then replies with a table of answers. That way you avoid network roundtrips and can use some internal optimizations on the ABAP side when there is information to be shared between those requests.

Comment: is it possible? I just made rough googling and found nothing. Anybody ever implemented this? Is it a standard functionality or not?

Comment: @Suncatcher It's nothing magic. Just a function module which processes requests in bulk.